# How to refresh ToolTipText on ToolStripButton?

Tags: c#, winforms, toolstrip, toolstripitem

I want to implement simple toggle functionality on a ToolStripButton.

View Mode --> Edit Mode

Edit Mode --> View Mode

This piece of code is working fine except that `ToolTip` doesn't refresh. I tried `AutoToolTip`  property. I also tried setting `ToolTipText` to `string.Empty`. But my toolstrip continues to show old tooltip text. `ToolTipText` should also change when I toggle.

```
private void btnTrackingMode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_currentSheetTrackingMode == SheetTrackingMode.ViewMode)
    {
        _currentTrackingMode = TrackingMode.EditMode;

        btnTrackingMode.AutoToolTip = true;
        btnTrackingMode.ToolTipText = string.Empty;
        btnTrackingMode.ToolTipText = "You are currently in Edit Mode. Click here to enter into View Mode";
        btnTrackingMode.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image) ((Image) new ComponentResourceManager(typeof(MyForm)).GetObject("btnTrackingEditMode.Image")));
        btnTrackingMode.ImageTransparentColor = System.Drawing.Color.Magenta;
    }
    else
    {
        _currentTrackingMode = TrackingMode.ViewMode;

        btnTrackingMode.AutoToolTip = true;
        btnTrackingMode.ToolTipText = string.Empty;
        btnTrackingMode.ToolTipText = "You are currently in View Mode. Click here to enter into Edit Mode";
        btnTrackingMode.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image) ((Image) new ComponentResourceManager(typeof(MyForm)).GetObject("btnTrackingViewMode.Image")));
        btnTrackingMode.ImageTransparentColor = System.Drawing.Color.Magenta;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried with Text property as well. No effect.

Comment: Setting Visible property false and enabling it back did the trick. Any better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to [refresh](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh(v=vs.110).aspx) the button's parent `ToolStrip`

```
btnTrackingMode.ToolTipText = "something";
//put your toolstrip's name here
buttonsToolStrip.Refresh();
```

You should be able to access the parent tool strip through [`btnTrackingMode.Owner`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.owner(v=vs.110).aspx) if it's not directly available for some reason.